# Disabling / Destroying Filepicker.io file upload selector

Tags: filepicker.io

We're using Filepicker.io in our application and it works really well. I need 2 options for this plugin that I can't find in their docs.

1) Disable - We only want a user to upload a single image per interaction. If Filepicker has already processed a file in the current interaction I'd like to disable the plugin until they submit the form, or remove the current image.

2) Destroy - Filepicker provides a way to programmatically convert a standard input field to a Filepicker.io widget: `constructWidget`. I don't find a `destroyWidget` function in the docs. Does anyone know if this is an option?

This is the code we're currently using:

```
<input id="upload-image-input" value="Upload an image." data-fp-
    services="COMPUTER,URL,FLICKR,FACEBOOK,INSTAGRAM,DROPBOX,PICASA"> 

var element = document.getElementById('upload-image-input')
    view = this;

// make sure filepicker isn't already displaying
if (element.style.display !== 'none') {
    element.type="filepicker-dragdrop";
    element.onchange = function(e){
        var text = view.set(e.fpfile.url),
    };
    filepicker.constructWidget(element);
}
```

I'd also like to know if there's an event which gets triggered when a file is removed using the drag and drop widget's "X" button.

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently have support for these features directly in the SDK, but there are ways to produce this behavior. For instance, you can add a custom class to the element and then use that to add event listeners, remove it from the dom, or disable it.

Comment: Brett, can you please provide some sample code? It looks like you work for FilePicker so I'd love some guidance please. I'm creating/deleting FilePicker for a posting window. Even though I'm explicitly removing events on my drop element FP keeps adding them back. Thus the next time I open the window, I have 2 of each event. Would love to talk to you about this.